# Issues excluding data in SSAS cube (different output in SSMS and SSAS using EOMONTH())

Tags: sql, ssas, sql-server-2016, olap-cube

I'm creating a cube whose stock values should only conclude the last day each month's balance and value.

Hence, I've created the following Query in SSMS:

```
 Create table #theStockTable(
 Stock int,
 StockValue INT,
 DateKey int
 )

 INSERT INTO #theStockTable
 VALUES(3,5, 20170211),
 (3,5,20170228),
 (1,4,20170331),
 (1,4,20170330)

SELECT        CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DateKey, 112) AS numeric(8, 0)) AS DateKey, SUM(Stock) AS [CL Stock], SUM(StockValue) AS [CL Stock Value]
FROM            #theStockTable
WHERE        CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateKey)) = eomonth(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), DateKey)))
GROUP BY DateKey
```

In SSMS this returns the correct values:

```
DateKey CL Stock    CL Stock Value
20170228    3   5
20170331    1   4
```

However, when I create an OLAP cube using SSAS, and use the Query above as the `Named Query` for my fact table `#theStockTable` and the same Query as my only partition of the same fact table and deploy and execute the cube, I have a situation where I get different values on each day of every month, but I only want to have the values for each month's **last day**.

I have used `New Project.. -> Import from Server (multidimensional model or data mining model)` in SSAS. *It is important that the users must be able to browse the cube as they presently do.*

The cube whose meta data I have copied contains every day's values on the stock table. May there be some metadata change I need to make in addition to the Query modification I have done in `Edit named Query..` in `Data Source View` and replacing the old Query in the partition with my new Query?

Hopefully someone can shed some light into this.

> EDIT

To clarify my request, some users of the cube has explained that it is rather slow to browse in for instance Excel, mainly because my `Stock` measure is much bigger than it is required to be. As it is now, it returns every `StockValue` and `Stock` of each product and each day. I want to only include the total balance of `StockValue` and `Stock` of the last day of the month. All other stock values are redundant.

For instance, browsing my `DimDate` dimension table with the measurements `Stock` and `StockValue` should have this return set:

```
DateKey     Stock   StockValue
20170131    0       0
```

rather than the whole return set which is returned now:

```
DateKey     Stock   StockValue
20170101    3       5
20170102    4       6
20170103    1       1
20170131    0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you already had a date dimension in your cube, if yes, then follow these steps:

1. Add an additional attribute [IsLastDay] with value 0/1 in the date dimension to indicate if the current date record is the last day of that month or not.

2.Add a calculate measure [CalStock] with this formular:

([Measures].[StockValue],[Date].[IsLastDay].&[1])

3.Fire this query to return the expected result:

```
select {[CalStock]} on 0,
non empty{[Date].[Date].[Date]} on 1
from [YourCube]
```

Comment: Sorry for a late response. Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to commit to this tasks as much as I have wanted to until now. Using this solution would, from my understanding, give an option to get the expected result by browsing the cube with a specific Query. I'm searching for a way to browse the cube with a specific Measure attribute. I'll try to implement your Query as a calculated member and test that. I'm having some issues to deploy the cube at the moment though.